# Redirect if login is correct

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React, I have the following form:

```
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="jeff@example.com" onChange={this.updateEmail.bind(this)} />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" onChange={this.updatePassword.bind(this)} />
            <button>Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

In case the login is correct, I would like to be redirected to the index page. So I would want something like this:

```
submit(e : Event) {
    e.preventDefault();

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function() {
      Link.to("/");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

However, I know that `Link.to("/")` does not exist. So what can I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use react routeur [push function](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc). The router can be pass to your component through context type

There is [some examples on how to do it](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#programmatic-navigation)

Globally, all routed components received a contextType `router`. In a routed component (one targetted by a react-router route), you need to inform React you need the router context that's why you must declare `contextTypes`. it looks like:

```
React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  triggerRedirect() {
    var router = this.context.router;
    router.push("/wynsure/dashboard");  
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to keep a global router across all files or can I just create one instance on the spot:          `let router = new Router();`
 `router.push("/");` ?

Comment: You need to use the one from contextTypes. I added an example in my comment.

Comment: Note that since react-router 2.4.0 you can use the high order component `withRouter` to pass the router to your component props. I find this way easier and cleaner than using React context. See this example: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/master-detail/app.js#L66